# convert SVG code into png in javascript

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I have javascript code : var win = ("data:image/svg xml;base64,"   Utils.encode64(svg)); 
in HTML5.
I want convert it into data:image/png;base64,.....

I tried with win= win.replace('data:image/png;base64,','');
But replaces the xml to png, but the it does not display the image correctly and giving an error message.

plz help to out..

Comment: As far as I am aware, this is not possible. PNG is not a vector format, nor is it a XML format, it is not compatible with SVG in any way.

Comment: In most browsers if add the SVG image to a `canvas` it will get converted to a bitmap automatically.

Comment: there is way to export svg into png.. check it.http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/.....i dcant find exact way of conversion